# Exception: missing } in XML expression

Tags: javascript, onedrive

I am getting this error Exception: missing } in XML expression and also when i open my html file in FIREFOX  and use Firebug 1.9.2, this error appear:

```
WL is not defined [Break On This Error]      
WL.Event.subscribe("auth.login", onLogin);`
```

Here is my code:

```
<html><head>
<title>Greeting the User Test page</title>
<script src="js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID = "id",
    REDIRECT_URL = "url";
    WL.Event.subscribe("auth.login", onLogin);
    WL.init({
        client_id: APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID,
        redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URL,
        scope: "wl.signin", 
        response_type: "token"
    });

    WL.ui({
        name: "signin",
        element: "signInButton",
        brand: "skydrive",
        type: "connect"
    });

    function greetUser(session) {
        var strGreeting = "";
        WL.api(
        {
            path: "me",
            method: "GET"
        },
        function (response) {
            if (!response.error) {
                strGreeting = "Hi, " + response.first_name + "!";
                document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = strGreeting;
            }
        });
    }

    function onLogin() {
        var session = WL.getSession();
        if (session) {
            greetUser(session);              
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Connect to display a welcome greeting.</p>
<div id="greeting"></div>
<div id="signInButton"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont know where is mistake, i just copy this sample code from skydrive api tutorial.
Of course, that I id and url strings replace with strings of my personal app. 
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the Javascript file from the Microsoft server:

```
<script src="http://js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `<script>` tag should look like:

```
<script src="http://js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or possibly

```
<script src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

if that site is configured properly. Without that, your URL was interpreted as being relative to the URL of your page.